# Can a C++ union perform math on the number it contains?

Tags: c++, unions, union-types

Is it possible in C++ to create a union that would let me do something like this ...

```
union myTime {
    long millis;
    double seconds;
};
```

BUT, have it somehow do the conversion so that if I input times in milliseconds, and then call seconds, it will take the number and divide it by 1000, or conversely, if I input the number in seconds, then call millis, it would multiply the number by 1000...

So that:

```
myTime.millis = 1340;

double s = myTime.seconds;
```

Where s would equal 1.34

or

```
myTime.seconds = 2.5;

long m = myTime.millis;
```

Where m would = 2500

Is this possible?

Comment: No. What problem are you specifically trying to solve? Is it purely time units as per your example? If your problem is simply to do with units of time, consider using [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) units, since you can have `double` as the representation and it will still implicitly perform the conversion for you. But this is highly specific to your example of `millis`/`seconds` -- so it's not a generic solution

Comment: `union` is just type, not a function or method so obviously it just stores data and doesn't do anything on its data

Comment: `union` is a super low-level construct intended for memory manipulation trickery. For higher-level unions, `std::variant` should be used, and for abstraction, classes.

Comment: @Human-Compiler - It is millis to seconds and back that I need to do, I was just thinking that if a union could do simple things like that, it would be a cool way to do simple conversions. It's for a microcontroller program so I can't really justify bringing in a library just to divide and multiply by 1000...  :-)

Comment: @MichaelSims It's not "bringing in a library", it's a header in _the_ standard library (`std`). It's required to come with the compiler since C++11 which is *ten years old*. It's _the_ modern and intended semantic way of dealing with time-points/durations. These types are mostly `constexpr` and don't even use heap memory. Unless you're on an older compiler, there's no rational reason to be avoiding the `<chrono>` header, even for microcontrollers.

Answer (score 2):

A `union` is just different representations for the same value (the same bytes), so you can't define any smart logic over that.

In this case, you can define a `class` with conversion functions (both for initializtion or for getting the data).

```
class myTime {
public:
    myTime(long millis);
    double as_seconds();

    static void from_seconds(double seconds);
};
```

Notice that as mentioned in other answers, for time conversions you can use `std::chrono` objects (c++11 and above)

Comment: @Elliott you would be wrong -- this is not how unions work. You cannot use unions to violate strict-aliasing -- which is what you are suggesting here with `struct Variables` and `int32_t`. Doing such thing is formally undefined behavior. You cannot type pun through unions in C++. The closest thing that you can _legally_ do is view the common initial sequence of objects in a union -- and this is only valid if they are layout-compatible and standard-layout (and this rule does not apply with non-structural types like `uint32_t`)

Comment: @MichaelSims It looks like the user I was responding to deleted their comment. They had said something about using a `struct` inside a `union` to be able to type-pun and access an `int32_t` as 4 `uint8_t` values -- but this is illegal in C++ (hence my reply)

Comment: @Human-Compiler - I have found the rigidity of C, in general, to be very difficult to get used to ... it's been a very steep learning curve for me.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as asked: **No.** Unions are lower-level structure that simply allow multiple object representations to live in the same memory space. In your example, `long` and `double` share the same address.

They are not, however, *smart* enough to automatically do a conversation of any kind. Accessing the inactive member of a `union` is actually undefined behavior in most cases (there are exceptions for if you have a common-initial sequence in a standard-layout object).

Even if the behavior were well-defined, the value you would see in the `double` would be the `double` interpretation of the byte-pattern necessary to represent `1340`.

---

If your problem is specifically to do with converting `millis` to `seconds`, as per your example, have you considered using [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) units? These units are designed specifically for automatically doing these conversions between time units for you -- and you are capable of defining durations with custom representations (such as `double`).

Your example in your problem could be rewritten:

```cpp
using double_seconds = std::chrono::duration<double>;
const auto millis = std::chrono::millis{1340};

const auto m = double_seconds{millis}; 

// m contains 1.340
```

Answer (score 1):

You can if you abuse the type system a bit:

```
union myTime {
    double seconds;
    class milli_t {
        double seconds;
     public:
        milli_t &operator=(double ms) {
            seconds = ms/1000.0;
            return *this; }
        operator double() const { return seconds * 1000; }
    } millis;
};
```

Now if you do

```
myTime t;
t.millis = 1340;
double s = t.seconds;
```

s would equal 1.34

and

```
myTime t;
t.seconds = 2.5;
long m = t.millis;
```

m would be 2500, exactly as you desire.

Of course, *why* you would want to do this is unclear.

Comment: It was just an idea to make some code a little cleaner because it deals a lot with converting milliseconds to seconds and back and I had used a union in another project for conversion between datatypes and so I just got to wondering if this was even possible. Thank you for showing this to me, I'm going to experiment with it.

Comment: Is there any way to make both numbers (.millis and .seconds) come back as unsigned long datatypes? I'm not interested in fractional seconds, so if a value of 2300 was entered as millis, then it should return 2 for seconds and seconds will never be assigned as a double they will always be whole numbers like 2, 5, etc. so in that case, millis should come back as 2000, 5000, etc.

Comment: You could change all the double types to long if you wanted.

Comment: I tried that, and whatever value I enter for .millis ... say .millis = 2345, it changes the return of millis to 2000, though the seconds are correct. and if I put in .seconds = 5 then it correctly kicks back seconds and millis ... but it's like it's rounding everything in the calculation somewhere when I just use long for the data types.

Comment: Also when I use the long data type and enter in a value for .millis less than a thousand, it changes it to 0 in the output. It must have something to do with that seconds = ms/1000 part of the function.

Comment: Actually, @Chris Dodd, when I take the value from the union and cast it to an unsigned long, it works perfectly... it's not as clean as I was hoping, but certainly functional.